# Save daily averages obtained from a monthly database to a csv format file

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas

I have a file 'tancoyol.csv' containing Fecha, Temperatura, Humedad, PreciAcu data recorded every 15 minutes. It has the following form:

Fecha                  DirViento   MagViento  Temperatura  HUmedad  PreciAcu
                                                                                          2011-07-01 00:00:00        318        6.6        21.22      100       1.7
2011-07-01 00:15:00        342        5.5        21.20      100       1.7
2011-07-01 00:30:00        329        6.6        21.15      100       4.8
2011-07-01 00:45:00        279        7.5        21.11      100       4.2
2011-07-01 01:00:00        318        6.0        21.16      100       2.5
2011-07-01 01:15:00        329        7.1        21.13      100       4.0
2011-07-01 01:30:00        300        4.7        21.15      100       1.3
2011-07-01 01:45:00        291        3.1        21.23      100       2.2
2011-07-01 02:00:00        284        7.6        21.29      100       1.3
2011-07-01 02:15:00        315        0.0        21.43      100       1.0
2011-07-01 02:30:00        281        3.6        21.47      100       3.2
2011-07-01 02:45:00          0        2.7        21.52      100       2.5
2011-07-01 03:00:00         57        1.2        21.53      100       0.0
2011-07-01 03:15:00        300        3.4        21.69      100       0.0
2011-07-01 03:30:00        359        5.9        21.67      100       0.0
2011-07-01 03:45:00        309        1.8        21.65      100       0.0
2011-07-01 04:00:00        244       13.4        21.64      100       0.0
2011-07-02 00:00:00        312        6.0        23.05       97       0.0
2011-07-02 00:15:00        318        6.3        22.79      100       0.3
2011-07-02 00:30:00        303        9.1        22.44      100       0.7
2011-07-02 00:45:00        323        6.3        22.40      100       0.3
2011-07-02 01:00:00        319        5.4        22.07      100       0.7
2011-07-02 01:15:00          4        3.9        21.89      100       0.8
2011-07-02 01:30:00          6        4.5        21.74      100       0.7
2011-07-02 01:45:00        310        5.0        21.72      100       1.3
2011-07-02 02:00:00        307        0.0        21.79      100       1.0
2011-07-02 02:15:00          5        3.4        21.78      100       1.2
2011-07-02 02:30:00        288        3.4        21.78      100       1.5
2011-07-02 02:45:00          0        2.6        21.66      100       1.5
2011-07-02 03:00:00        280        5.8        21.48      100       1.3
2011-07-02 03:15:00         29        0.0        21.43      100       1.5
2011-07-02 03:30:00        332        2.0        21.23      100       1.7
2011-07-02 03:45:00        148        0.0        21.06      100       1.5
2011-07-02 04:00:00        132        0.0        21.00      100       2.0
2011-07-03 00:00:00        308        8.0        21.93       99       0.3
2011-07-03 00:15:00        288       14.4        21.85       99       0.2
2011-07-03 00:30:00        354        3.1        21.85       99       0.3
2011-07-03 00:45:00        335        5.8        21.75      100       0.2
2011-07-03 01:00:00        274        2.7        21.68      100       0.0
2011-07-03 01:15:00        328        5.6        21.55      100       0.3
2011-07-03 01:30:00        319        7.9        21.38      100       0.2
2011-07-03 01:45:00        322        5.1        21.32      100       0.3
2011-07-03 02:00:00        317        2.8        21.21      100       0.2
2011-07-03 02:15:00        322        5.3        21.08      100       0.3
2011-07-03 02:30:00        291        4.3        21.06      100       0.2
2011-07-03 02:45:00        284        5.7        21.04      100       0.3
2011-07-03 03:00:00        310        2.7        21.05      100       0.2
2011-07-03 03:15:00        318        4.6        21.06      100       0.3
2011-07-03 03:30:00        299        7.4        21.05      100       0.2
2011-07-03 03:45:00        238        0.0        20.99      100       0.3
2011-07-03 04:00:00        310        1.4        21.05      100       0.2

The first thing I want to do is get the average of the columns for DirViento, MagViento, Temperatura and Humedad. I do this as follows:

`import pandas as pd`
`import numpy as np`

`df = pd.read_csv('tancoyol.csv', parse_dates=[['Fecha','Hora']])`
`df1=df.set_index('Fecha_Hora')`
`prom_diario=df1.resample('D',how=np.mean)`
`print prom_diario`

Fecha    DirViento  MagViento  Temperatura     Humedad  PreciAcu

2011-07-01  318.000000   6.600000    21.220000  100.000000  1.700000
2011-07-02  273.470588   5.064706    21.474706   99.823529  1.688235
2011-07-03  200.705882   3.864706    21.775882   99.941176  1.076471
2011-07-04  306.812500   4.925000    21.310625   99.875000  0.231250

because the average is not done for days 1, 2 and 3, since the output is lagged, ie, the average for day 2 should correspond to the first day and so on. How to resolve this problem?
Now, instead of obtaining the average in the PreciAcu column, I would like to get the daily sum only for PreciAcu column, How I can do it? 
Finally, How storing the outputs (average and sum) to a csv file

I will appreciate very much for your help

Comment: In future questions, consider including just a sample of your data. This might be too much.

Answer (score 0):

To sum one column and average others, pass a dictionary of column names and functions.

```
In [47]: df.resample('D', {'DirViento': np.mean, 'MagViento': np.mean, 'Temperatura': np.mean, 'HUmedad': np.mean, 'PreciAcu': np.sum})
Out[47]: 
            PreciAcu  Temperatura     HUmedad   DirViento  MagViento
 0_1                                                                 
2011-07-01      30.4    21.367059  100.000000  273.823529   5.100000
2011-07-02      18.0    21.841765   99.823529  200.941176   3.747059
2011-07-03       4.0    21.347059   99.823529  306.882353   5.105882
```

I don't follow your reasoning for why the output is lagged, but you can achieve it like this:

```
In [53]: resampled = df.resample('D', {'DirViento': np.mean, 'MagViento': np.mean, 'Temperatura': np.mean, 'HUmedad': np.mean, 'PreciAcu': np.sum})

In [54]: resampled.tshift(-1)
Out[54]: 
            PreciAcu  Temperatura     HUmedad   DirViento  MagViento
0_1                                                                 
2011-06-30      30.4    21.367059  100.000000  273.823529   5.100000
2011-07-01      18.0    21.841765   99.823529  200.941176   3.747059
2011-07-02       4.0    21.347059   99.823529  306.882353   5.105882
```

To save it to a CSV is happily easy: `df1.to_csv('filename.csv')`.

Comment: I had no idea that you could pass a `dict` to `how`!

Comment: How parse the data? You could write a line like parse data for get averages and sums? , I follow getting the same result, I followed your suggestions, but to run my script, the operations obtained do not take into account the first line and I believe that evil is in the form of parse my data.
Traductor de Google para empresas:Translator ToolkitTraductor de sitios webGlobal Market Finder

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `closed='right'` and `label='right'` arguments of `resample`:

```
In [38]: hows = {'PreciAcu': 'sum'}

In [39]: func_keys = df.columns - Index(hows.keys())

In [40]: mean_funcs = zip(func_keys, ['mean'] * len(func_keys))

In [41]: hows.update(mean_funcs)

In [42]: hows
Out[42]:
{'DirViento': 'mean',
 'HUmedad': 'mean',
 'MagViento': 'mean',
 'PreciAcu': 'sum',
 'Temperatura': 'mean'}

In [48]: df.resample('D', how=hows, closed='right', label='right')
Out[48]:
            PreciAcu  HUmedad  Temperatura  DirViento  MagViento
ts
2011-07-01       1.7  100.000       21.220    318.000      6.600
2011-07-02      28.7   99.824       21.475    273.471      5.065
2011-07-03      18.3   99.941       21.776    200.706      3.865
2011-07-04       3.7   99.875       21.311    306.812      4.925
```

And of course as @Dan Allan says, use `to_csv` to write your newly resampled `DataFrame` to a file.